# Wait in a loop, till I get the right response

Tags: jmeter

Scenario:

1)  I have a tool which keeps generating data in Database. (E.g. It creates 200 users and it takes say 10 minutes)

2)  I will trigger the tool to generate the users, meanwhile I need to loop through the Response till I get the 200 users count.

The suggestion I’m looking for is, the optimized way to achieve the above mentioned scenario.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: wrap the test so that you have control over when your tool is finished and when the test should start and synchronise it that way?

Comment: Use jmeter while controller and include HTTP request as part of that controller. Use regular expression extractor (as child of HTTP request) to store the user count and create a relevant condition in the While controller.